# IntelliJ IDEA generate signed bundle

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

I want to generate a signed bundled with IntelliJ IDEA but I always get this error no matter what I'm doing. I tried to upgrade to the Android Gradle version. I even downloaded Android Studio and set everything(updating the Gradle, sync, etc) but still the same error during the same project. Any idea how to fix it?

I took a screenshot of the error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwTup.png

Answer (score 0):

try to make your android level Gradle dependencies look like this:
`dependencies { classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5' classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4' }`
the gradle:3.6.4 works for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following line to your ***dependencies*** block

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
```

For a clean code I would suggestyou parametrize the version number, so you would add the following line to ***buildscript*** block:

```
ext.gradle_version = 'x.y.z' // Replace with that in your current build.gradle
ext.googleservices_version = '4.3.5'
```

and dependencies will look like

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:$googleservices_version'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradle_version'
}
```